# Python shutil pack a zip file and unzip it back EOF error

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Update: short answer, do not pack the archive to the same path as file source dir, the bug code in question is following**

```
shutil.make_archive(zip_path, 'zip', tmpdir)
```

Original Question:

I am using `shutils` to pack and unpack a Tensorflow model folder (I think this issue is more related to `shutils`)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
def load_model_as_bytes(model):
    def file_chunk_generate(file_path):
        CHUNK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                piece = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE);
                if len(piece) == 0:
                    return
                yield ByteChunk(buffer=piece)
        return file_chunk_generator

    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    tf.saved_model.save(model, tmpdir)
    zip_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, "tf_model")
    shutil.make_archive(zip_path, 'zip', tmpdir)
    size = os.path.getsize(f'{zip_path}.zip')
    logging.info(f"send model file zip, length: {size}") #-------output 4621
    file_chunk_generator = file_chunk_generate(f'{zip_path}.zip')
    return file_chunk_generator

class NeuralNetworkPart(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = Dense(10)

    def call(self, x):
        x = x[0]
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.d2(x)

model = NeuralNetworkPart()
it = load_model_as_bytes(model)
tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
zip_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, "tf_model.zip")
with open(zip_path, 'wb') as f:
    for byte_chunk in it:
        f.write(byte_chunk.buffer)
        logging.info(f"receive model file zip, length: {os.path.getsize(zip_path)}") #-------output 4621

shutil.unpack_archive(zip_path, tmpdir)
```

Basically this program get a folder, using `make_archive` to zip it. Then read the zip file as bytes, store it in a generator variable, and use the generator to write another zip file, and try to use `unpack_archive` to unzip it.

Before the byte generator is written, and after the zip file is written before unpack, the size are the same (checked in the logging), however when calling unpack, it raise EOF error

```
    shutil.unpack_archive(zip_path, tmpdir)
  File "/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 983, in unpack_archive
    func(filename, extract_dir, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 901, in _unpack_zipfile
    data = zip.read(info.filename)
  File "/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1338, in read
    return fp.read()
  File "/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 858, in read
    buf += self._read1(self.MAX_N)
  File "/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 940, in _read1
    data += self._read2(n - len(data))
  File "/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 975, in _read2
    raise EOFError
```

Comment: You're... not returning the generator at all..?

Comment: @AKX updated.. just a mistake when posting question.. The file sizes are correct so this function should work

Comment: I don't understand why you're going through the trouble of having that generator at all, when you could tell `load_model_as_bytes` the destination path you want that zip in.

Comment: @AKX the purpose is the serialization, the byte generator is going through the network.

Comment: I know there are plenty workarounds, just wondering why this does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This slightly simplified version seems to work just fine. Note that none of the temporary files are cleaned up by this; you might want to fix that before you have your tmpdir full of TensorFlow models.

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile


def file_chunk_generate(file_path):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            piece = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
            if not piece:
                return
            yield piece


def get_zip_chunk_generator(source_dir):
    arcname = shutil.make_archive(
        os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp("zip-"), "tf_model"), "zip", source_dir
    )
    return file_chunk_generate(arcname)


def make_source_dir():
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp("src-")
    for x in range(5):
        with open(os.path.join(tmpdir, f"test-{x}.txt"), "wb") as f:
            f.write(b"foo" * 1024)
    return tmpdir


source_dir = make_source_dir()
it = get_zip_chunk_generator(source_dir)
dest_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="dest-")
print("1", os.listdir(dest_dir))
zip_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, "tf_model_dest.zip")
with open(zip_path, "wb") as f:
    for byte_chunk in it:
        f.write(byte_chunk)
print("2", os.listdir(dest_dir))
shutil.unpack_archive(zip_path, dest_dir)
print("3", os.listdir(dest_dir))
```

The output is

```
1 []
2 ['tf_model_dest.zip']
3 ['test-0.txt', 'test-1.txt', 'test-3.txt', 'test-2.txt', 'tf_model_dest.zip', 'test-4.txt']
```

as you might expect.

I'd recommend using tarballs though if you're going to stream over the network (since you could indeed do that without any file on disk at all; ZIPs require seeking support to unpack, but TARs don't).

Comment: This works fine. I would break down to figure out the reason why the original version does not work.

Comment: I found the bug cause and updated in the question. I used to think the function works something like `dest = src + dest` so I could pass `dest` as args, seems I am wrong. It would crash somehow.